# NSDate timeIntervalSince1970 gives few milliseconds ahead

Tags: ios, timestamp, nstimeinterval

I am trying to get the current timestamp using `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` . When printing its value I get a log `1406548777.463378` whereas when checked on http://www.epochconverter.com/ the current timestamp was close to `1406548758` . Can someone please highlight on the following difference.

Comment: I guess that site is giving rounded value where as NS API is returning precised value till 6 decimal.

Comment: what's your concern. is it 6 decimal places precision or the difference in the main value?

Comment: I am confused.  This is the *current time* since epoch and given they are different isn't that simply that either or both clocks are incorrect or there is a difference in time between checking the timestamp?

Comment: The difference in the main value is causing an issue. Can u tell me wat could be the reason?

Comment: Is your "current timestamp" for both cases the same? For example, your code may run on macbook or iPhone with different device time and www.epochconverter.com may be using its own server time as reference?